# Is HTML Import still supported in Google Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, web-component, html-imports

According to http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-html-imports

> To enable HTML imports in Chrome, go to chrome://flags and enable the Enable HTML Imports flag. Once you’re done, click the Relaunch Now button at the bottom of the screen to restart Chrome with support for HTML imports.

But I can't find it in latest version of Google Chrome flags

Comment: It has been deprecated and will never become official. Consider it dead.

Comment: @RyanWheale ok thanks so I search the web on html imports dead I can read "Mozilla and Microsoft argue that further work on HTML Imports should wait until ES6 module loading is finished." http://www.2ality.com/2015/08/web-component-status.html so for me it may be temporary like web components ?

Comment: That is correct - ES6 modules will shape the direction of html imports, for sure. In the mean time, there are plenty of tools which can do it for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTML Imports are implemented natively in [Chrome, Opera and Android](http://caniuse.com/#search=html%20imports).

It is still a [W3C Working Draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-imports/).

For other browsers, you can use:

- the [webcomponentsjs](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs) polyfill,
- or directly the file `html-imports.min.js` from [HTML Imports](https://github.com/webcomponents/html-imports).

**Update 2019**

HTML Imports [won't be supported natively](https://caniuse.com/#search=html%20imports) after Chrome 73. You should then use another solutions:

- the polyfill,
- an alternate module loader,
- JS `import` combined with [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals),
- a direct download with `fetch()`.

**Update 2020**

HTML Imports were definitvely removed.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternate way to do the same. I put the whole file to be imported,in a string,
then call document.write(theString) .for example

```
//head.js
var s= 
`<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Program/assets/css/main.css">
<script src="/Program/assets/js/my.js"></script>
<script src="/Program/libs/highlight/highlight.pack.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/Program/libs/highlight/androidstudio2.css'>
<script src='/Program/assets/js/jquery.3.4.1.js' ></script>
<script>
$('code').each(function() {
   var that = $(this);
   var html = that.html().trim();
   that.empty();
   that.text(html);
 });
 hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
</script>
`;

document.write(s);
```

then I call this  newly created script file instead of the main file:

```
 <script src="/Program/head.js"></script>
```